# Get all instance of a specific control

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, controls, enumerate

I would like to retrieve all of a specific control. For example let's say `SysListView32`. I would like to later `SendMessage` to them. Could anyone help me.

I tried many ways, but I was able just to retrieve the class of a window, not all it's controls.

Comment: your english is fine, but you need to post your code for this question so we can help.

Comment: I don't really have any initializing code, since all my code will bebuilt on this. I could enumerate all the windows, but I'm not sure how to catch the controls of it.

Comment: you said you had tried many ways. what did that code look like?

Comment: don't you have the resource id's? having them, you could use GetDlgItem for each

Comment: I mean I tried to google a lot, but couldn't find any helpful. I've just got no idea where could I start.

I know I can enumerate windows, but even if I enumerate them I've got no idea how can I retrieve it's controls.